# Overlapping labels in legend in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to avoid overlapping the lagend labels in ggplot?

[image]

```
ggplot(g3, aes(variable, country, fill= value)) + geom_tile() +
theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, size = 15), legend.position="bottom", legend.text = element_text(size = 15, angle = 50),
     axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

Comment: there is a difference between `java` and `javascript`

Comment: You may want to use the `hjust` parameter in `element_text()`.

Comment: @mikebader thank you so much! It works!

Comment: Yay!!! I'm so glad =)

Answer (score 0):

For axis labels, the best way to fix this is to use the `ggplot2::guide_axis()` function, which will adjust both the angle and vertical/horizontal positioning at the same time. You can also make your legend labels easier to read by scaling the label. This might obviate the need to rotate the legend labels. For example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(g3, aes(variable, country, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  scale_fill_continuous(labels = scales::label_number(scale = 10000, suffix = "k")) +
  guides(x = guide_axis(angle = 45), fill = guide_colorbar(direction = "horizontal)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", text = element_text(size = 15))
```

Comment: Ohhh! It is so great! I am a beginner in R but I try to learn more from courses, forums. Every answer means little help for me. I`ve tried your suggested code and the graph is super wow. Thank you!

Comment: Could you accept this answer as the answer to your question?